# Manga where the main character is summoned twice and gets two different classes

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for a manga where the main character gets summoned to another world with some people and gets the class 'god', which lets him be able to do anything. Then he gets summoned again along with some people by the demon lord and get a class 'demon lord' or something, which gives him the power to manipulate reality.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the art or the appearance of the characters?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215336/isekai-manga-hero-summoned-a-second-time might be relevant.

Comment: Maybe this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/236009

Answer (score 2):

## Summoned to a parallel fantasy world many times

It might be "[めっちゃ召喚された件](https://anilist.co/manga/134141/Metcha-Shoukan-Sareta-Ken-THE-COMIC/)" (in romaji "*Metcha Shoukan Sareta Ken THE COMIC*"), translated as "**Summoned to a parallel fantasy world many times**".

### First volume cover

[image: めっちゃ召喚された件 cover]

### Synopsis

> Guy's whole class gets summoned to another world, except he's the only who one was transferred to a different one. Just when he gets used to his new life, he gets summoned to another world again, and again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Could you explain how this title matches what the question is asking about?  Does the protagonist get "god" and "demon lord" classes?

Comment: i love this manga it's a masterpiece.